# Android Studio RecyclerView import problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, import, widget

I'm currently receiving an error when trying to import recycler view for my project.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.zooapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'
}
```

And here is the start of my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class AnimalsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final ImageView animalIcon;
    private final TextView animalName;
```

When it is like this and I try to click a button to open a new activity ( where the recycler view is supposed to be ) the app just crashes and says:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
```

Then when I remove the androidx and add the import that has to be there with the V7.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

The v7 becomes red and so does the  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder.
If I try to ALT + ENTER to import it again the androidx appears.

Since this is from a practical at university it is supposed to be with the android.support.v7.

Comment: You will have to migrate it to AppCompat in order to run the application

Answer (score 2):

Change your recyclerView block to below code
if you are using androidx dependency for RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: @Valeri Vladimirov Welcome 

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AndroidX in your project

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on **Refactor**
3. Click on **Migrate to AndroidX**
4. It will ask you to make a **zip** first. Click **Ok**

If you want to use AppCompat in your project

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on **Refactor**
3. Click on **Migrate to AppCompat**
4. It will ask you to make a **zip** first. Click **Ok**

Answer (score 1):

link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#1.1.0

```
 //Add this
  dependencies
  {
   implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
   // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
   implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"
  }
```

//in xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_defulterList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve adding this dependency in app gradle file:

```
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```